# What are the best ways to check multiple conditions in the makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make argument that can have three values, say A, B and C.

I wrote the following in makefile:

```
ifeq ("$(PLATFORM)", "A")
     echo "PLATFORM A"
else ifeq("$(PLATFORM)", "B")
     echo "PLATFORM B"
else
     echo "PLATFORM C"
```

with this I cannot execute all the three cases.

I use:

```
make PLATFORM="A"
make PLATFORM="B"
make PLATFORM="C"
make
```

I found similar solutions in stack overflow, but nothing works for me

I am using GNU make 3.81

Comment: You should first define (for yourself) what type of value PLATFORM is really carrying. Obviously you want it to be a collection of platform names, not a single one, but your programmed cases do not match this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the makefile is the missing `space` after `ifeq`.

However I look for better solutions that are more `portable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more context what you are trying to achieve.  I might use something like this:

```
include platform/$(PLATFORM).mk
```

and separate makefiles for each platform in the `platform` subdirectory.

Comment: Here platform is a make argument that I took as an example. Platform is not the literal platform. You can replace it with any other variable

Comment: But that's not a reason by itself that the `include` directive would not work.